# Which IDE to use for Go?

Tags: ide, go

Awhile back when Go was fairly new I played around with it a bit using Vi or Notepad++ as an editor, at the time there were no IDE's available. Now I'm planning to do some work with it and after a quick search found there are several options. After that I took a look at SO and found all the questions regarding Go IDE's were dated.

So, now that there are some options it's time for me to ask; What IDE would you recommend for Go? Why? I don't care which OS(s) it runs on but please make a note of which. Basic feature bullet points would be appreciated though not entirely necessary.

Comment: My current choice for all languages is TextMate: it can handle text and invoke compiler. What else matters? :)

Comment: I use ViM for editing with the syntastic plugin to check for errors and bash for compiling/running. That's also what I use for Javascript, Ruby, Python, C, D...

Comment: Why was this closed? I can find this same question for 5 other languages like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Please (re)read the locked message on the Python question, these types of questions may have been acceptable at one point in SE's history, but are not any longer.

Comment: @jonsca okay, fair enough. Although, the members of SO clearly still want these questions.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal even though I provided an answer below knowing these topics get closed, I prefer this to set a precedent against spin off questions, and stop SO from turning into an opinionated forum. I come here for the cut and dry answer, but that's just me :)

Comment: To get Jetbrains to create a dedicated Go IDE, vote here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5938

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of complete options, and github.com/nsf/gocode is a helpful part of that. The go src includes binding for vim (what I've been using for the longest) and emacs. Ctags and go seem to play well together with CtrlP and tagbar can be augmented to work as well if that's your thing.

I recently started using sublime text 2 and the plugin GoSublime. Code completion, auto format code, quick bindings for running pkg unit tests out of the box, lots of nice things to be productive.

If you already have a vim setup you enjoy, then roll with that b/c it works great. I'm rather impressed with sublime text myself and plan to (try and) use it going forward.

Comment: +1 for Sublime Text 2 and GoSublime.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone can answer this for you, as it is a very personal thing. So to that effect, [here](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/) is a listing of the currently available editors and Go-related plugins.

I don't know if it is complete, but it will at least get you started.

Edit: Personally, I use Gedit for everything. It has facilities to hook up whatever external tools I need, although I rarely use them. The only Go-related thing I do use is the syntax highlighting. When it comes to Go, I find there is not much need for a full-blown IDE. Languages like C#, C++, Java are just not productive when used without a whole IDE framework built around it. Go does not have this problem.